# Does Google include the time to load images, for a single page, as part of the page speed?

Tags: seo, google, page-speed

we all know that Google's affects your page rank with the load time of a page. How? That's part of the secret sauce. But we know that page speed is a serious factor.

So -> what is considered the speed of a page?

Is it just the first (and main) html file which the GET receives? Or does it also include loading of images as part of that speed.

so for example...

`GET /index.htm <- takes 0.45 seconds to retrieve (including DNS lookup before).`

*robot parses page.. see's there's a single main image....*

`GET /img/main.png <- takes 5 seconds to download.`

is the page speed for that resource, 0.45 seconds OR 5.45 seconds?

I understand Javascript is not fired .. but are any of these external resources all downloaded and part of the page speed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, they do count images. The count how long it takes to download the HTML and all static (JavaScript, CSS) and embedded content (images, flash) on the page.

From [here](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Webmasters/thread?tid=642b7eeb31842800&hl=en) (this isn't specifically about Google algorithm but it matches everything I have found about it so far including [Matt Cutts post](http://www.mattcutts.com/blog/site-speed/)):

> The "Performance overview" graph in
>   the Labs Site performance page tracks
>   the total loading time of the page,
>   from the initial request to the point
>   the browser finishes its rendering.
>   This includes the downloading of the
>   page, the related assets (CSS,
>   Javascript, images, etc), and the time
>   the browser needs to execute the
>   Javascript.

Additional anecdotal evidence would be [Google's official announcement about this change in their algorithm](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2010/04/using-site-speed-in-web-search-ranking.html) they mention Page Speed tools. All of them recommend optimizing images both in size and download speed (usually through uise of a CDN or cookieless domain).

Comment: Awesome @John Conde :) That answers my question perfectly AND the links also are great. Cheers mate!